# multiprocessing.Pool: how to kill the entire pool when parent is killed from the outside?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing.Pool, my code looks like this:

```
with Pool(10) as pool:
     result = pool.imap(function, data)
```

The code works as it should, but when I kill the parent job the pool of processes stays open. I am using Jenkins, so it's quite common to run a job and decide to stop it halfway.

How can I get all the pool killed when the parent is killed? Could you provide a working example?

Comment: How are you killing the parent job? SIGKILL? It should clean up all the processes on the way out the door for most other signals.

Comment: I don't know how it is killed. I am using jenkins and there is a button to kill jobs. My job is a shell script from where I run the python script.